# How to import one column to a new worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has individual worksheets detailing client stock trading data, and a master worksheet which has month to date and week to date totals for the clients.

I would like to set up a new worksheet titled week to date which will import the week to date column from the master worksheet and save it.
Additionally, I would like it to update every time I run the macro so it has an up to date record of the week to date figures.

My current code provides sum totals for specified columns on each worksheet, and embeds the contents of the active worksheet into the body of an outlook email.

```
Sub AutoSum()

    Dim wscount As Long
    wscount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To wscount
        Sheets(i).Select
        Range("K3").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
        Dim cel1 As String, cel2 As String
        cel1 = ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).End(xlUp).Address
        cel2 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address
        ActiveCell.Value = "=sum(" & (cel1) & ":" & (cel2) & ")"
    Next i

    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
    'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "nabil.hure@dnb.no"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Today's Trades" & Date
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send                                    'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Your code is pretty different than the question. Would does not work on your macro? What do you want to add/modify?

Comment: What I'd like to do is have a separate worksheet titled "wtd", and add code to my current macro which would export data from column K on my master worksheet to this new worksheet. I hope this clears things up a little and apologies if my question was vague. I do not know how to code this which is why I'm looking for help :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just asking how to cut a column across into another worksheet. This will move everything in the K column in the master sheet and copy it to the A column in wtd. Obviously this can be changed to any column you want.

```
Sheets("wtd").Range("A:A").Value = Sheets("master").Range("K:K").Value
```